# What is an adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

I've seen adapters used for various xml groups such as listview imageview, gallery, exactly what does it do. I read the documentation on google but it doesnt seem to help me.

Comment: Watch this video by Romain Guy on ListView. This should clear up some things. http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Answer (score 3):

An adapter connects a consumer (such as an `AdapterView`, like a `ListView`) to a data source in a custom way.

The consumer essentially requests individual views from the adapter, whose responsibility is to build them.

Comment: thanks, i know its a dumb question but ive been struggling on this stuff for the past week.